# What does the meet of two sigma algebras mean?

Tags: measure-theory, sigma-algebra

I came across this notation of which I am unfamiliar;

$\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{G}_{1}\vee \mathscr{G}_{1}$

where $\mathscr{G}_{1}$ and $\mathscr{G}_{2}$ are both sigma-fields of subsets of $\Omega$. It is claimed $\mathscr{F}$ is larger than both of $\mathscr{G}_{1}$ and $\mathscr{G}_{2}$ suggesting to me that

$\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{G}_{1}\vee \mathscr{G}_{1}=\mathscr{G}_{1}\cup \mathscr{G}_{1}$

but I know this last union is not always a sigma-field so perhaps this is not the meaning here?

Staying on this subject, would the notation $\mathscr{G}_{1}\subset\mathscr{G}_{2}$ mean the same as $\mathscr{G}_{1}\leq\mathscr{G}_{2}$, the latter statement which (I assume anyway) means $\mathscr{G}_{2}$ is finer than $\mathscr{G}_{1}$?

For some reason I cannot seem to find a clear definition of this for sigma-fields - sets, partitions etc yes, but not sigma fields - for example here;

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1345598/does-meet-of-two-partitions-of-a-set-always-exist

Any help as ever appreciated.

Comment: Offhand, I would expect this to be defined within the context of a lattice, as explained at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet).  The natural lattice in this context would be that of all sigma-fields defined on $\Omega;$ the (partial) ordering would be that inherited from the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Omega).$  In other words, the meet would be the coarsest sigma-field of which both components are subfields.  That's not usually their union--it will be bigger.  It would help to know the context in which you came across this notation in case some other lattice is understood.

Comment: Thank you @whuber. As I responded to Jonas I believe his answer is correct given the context - I think you are describing the same thing in the sense that $\sigma(\mathcal{G}_{1}\cup \mathcal{G}_{2})$ is this coarsest sigma-field you mention? The context I found this in is "coarsening at random" - essentially where loss of information occurs with censoring or missing values in repeated measures. In this context $\mathcal{G}_{1}$ represents the sigma-field generated by the indicator variable denoting if a random variable is observed, and $\mathcal{G}_{2}$ is for the random variable itself.

Comment: Yes, he is describing the same thing in a more basic way.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to answer this question, since it is essentially about notation. So my answer contains a bit of clever guessing.

Indeed, $\mathcal{G_1} \cup \mathcal{G_2}$ is in general no $\sigma$-field. Therefore, one may set  $$\mathcal{G_1} \vee  \mathcal{G_2} = \sigma( \mathcal{G_1} \cup \mathcal{G_2}),$$
where $\sigma(C)$ denotes the $\sigma$-field that is generated by the set system $C \subseteq 2^\Omega$. This function is defined by
$$\sigma(C) = \bigcap \left\lbrace \mathcal{G} : \mathcal{G} \supseteq C, \mathcal{G} \text{ is $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$}\right\rbrace. $$

Comment: Thank you @Jonas for your answer - this makes sense to me given the context I encountered the notation. So essentially $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{G}_{1}\vee \mathcal{G}_{2}$ is the smallest sigma-field containing $\mathcal{G}_{1}\cup \mathcal{G}_{2}$ in the sense that if $\mathcal{F}'$ is another sigma-field $\mathcal{G}_{1}\cup \mathcal{G}_{2}\subset\mathcal{F}'$ then $\mathcal{F}'\subset\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: In the last line, I would say $\mathcal{F}' \supseteq \mathcal{F}$, since $ \mathcal{F}$ is indeed the _smallest_ $\sigma$-field that contains $\mathcal{G_1}\cup \mathcal{G_2}$.

Comment: of course - my mistake! Thank you for the confirmation